# Tracking website registrations via

Tags: google-analytics, goal-tracking

I'm using Google Analytics Goals to track website registration. 
Registration page is /register and after successful registration it goes to /success page.

I'm trying to track registration from various links on website so that I can find out registrations against these links.

In Goals destination is

```
/register/success
```

And there is one funnel with this URL and UTM tracking.

```
/register?utm_source=JoinLink&utm_medium=web
```

It doesn't work.

Am I missing something or it is not possible to do it in this way?

My thinking was that I can use UTM and add various tracking links to find out number of registrations coming from these links. Can't we use UTM in this case?

Answer (score 0):

No, we can't. 
As I've figured out [here](http://productforums.google.com/forum/#!topic/analytics/-LgNYcMmkkQ) the utm parameters are ommited.
The workaround is to use a special url like this

```
/register_special
```

I'm not sure whether GA will track url params like this

```
/register?special=123
```